# Invoke WCF service from SQL without CLR

Tags: sql-server, web-services, wcf

Is it possible to invoke a WCF service from SQL without using a CLR? (like with asmx).

The following code works perfectly with an asmx service, but not with WCF

```
    --INTERNAL PARAMETERS
    DECLARE @Object AS INT
    DECLARE @ResponseText AS VARCHAR(8000)
    DECLARE @SiteURL AS VARCHAR(100) = fGetSiteUrl()

    --BUILD SERVICE URL
    DECLARE @ServiceURL VARCHAR(MAX) = @SiteURL + '/WebServices/PortalService.asmx/CreateUser'
                                        + '?userName=' + @UserName
                                        + '&password=' + @ClearTextPassword
                                        + '&question=' + @PasswordQuestion
                                        + '&answer=' + @PasswordAnswer
                                        + '&email=' + @Email

    --BUILD AND EXECUTE SERVICE CALL
    EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',@ServiceURL, 'false'
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT
    EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object

    --STRIP OUT USELESS FLUFF
    SET @ResponseText = SUBSTRING(@ResponseText, CHARINDEX('>', @ResponseText) + 1, (LEN(@ResponseText) - CHARINDEX('>', @ResponseText)))
    SET @ResponseText = SUBSTRING(@ResponseText, CHARINDEX('>', @ResponseText) + 1, (LEN(@ResponseText) - CHARINDEX('>', @ResponseText)))
    SET @ResponseText = CONCAT('<Result>', @ResponseText)

    DECLARE @MyXML XML  = @ResponseText

    --GET THE USER USERID OF THE NEW USER
    SET @UserId =   (SELECT     a.b.value('UserId[1]','nvarchar(1280)') AS UserId
                    FROM        @MyXML.nodes('Result') a(b))
```

Comment: A SOAP request is just an HTTP request. You could make it work, but you'll have to rebuild a valid request.

Comment: Could you point me in a direction? This is fairly uncharted territory for me